# how to add text in Manage Products -> Product -> Images in magento 1.9.3 admin panel

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to inform the user that upload a particular size of images for products in admin panel for symmetry in design on frontend so I want to add text at images tab of manage products. Following is the picture and I have put arrow sign where I want to add text.
[image]

I search in coding but nothing found. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The text block is defined in:

```
app/design/adminhtml/{theme}/{theme}/template/catalog/product/helper/gallery.phtml
```

The relevant translation file is:

```
app/locale/xx_XX/Mage_Catalog.csv
```

---

*A note on how to find test strings:*

One of the easiest ways to find a text string in the code base if you're not sure where to look for it is to `grep` it.

An example of how to use it (just make sure you use a text string that is more or less unique and does not contain variable [if unsure just try shorter parts of any given text string]):

```
grep -r "Maximum width and height dimension for upload image is" ./app
```

Example output:

```
user@server /www # grep -R "Maximum width and height dimension for upload image is " ./app
./app/locale/en_US/Mage_Catalog.csv:"Maximum width and height dimension for upload image is %s.","Maximum width and height dimension for upload image is %s."
./app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/helper/gallery.phtml:                <?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Maximum width and height dimension for upload image is %s.', Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image::XML_NODE_PRODUCT_MAX_DIMENSION)); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Christoph. Sorry to check it so late as I was busy in other projects.

Comment: No issue, I'm happy if it was helpful :) In case you had a chance to check it out on your project already and it worked for you I'm looking forward to get it accepted as an answer though :D